# Wordpress - Rewrite rules and taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-taxonomy

I have created a new Taxonomy called `typology` and I have assigned my post to that.
Taxonomy in this case are `shopping` and `food`

I also need to add category to my url so I have set in permalink `location` as base category and create a custom structure:

`/%typology%/%category%/%postname%`

I need to be able to visit links like this:

```
/shopping/location/italy/
/shopping/location/italy/milan/
/food/location/italy/
/food/location/italy/milan/
```

so I have created custom rewrite rules:

```
foreach ($typologies as $typology) {
        // transport/page/2
        add_rewrite_rule(
            $typology.'/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$',
            'index.php?paged=$matches[1]&typology='.$typology,
            'top'
        );
        // transport/location/italy/page/2
        add_rewrite_rule(
            $typology.'/'.$category_base.'/(.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$',
            'index.php?mlt_location=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]&typology='.$typology,
            'top'
        );
        // transport/location/italy
        add_rewrite_rule(
            $typology.'/'.$category_base.'/(.+?)/?$',
            'index.php?typology='.$typology.'&mlt_location=$matches[1]',
            'top'
        );
    }
```

`mlt_location` is a custom rewrite tag linked to a function that get the segment after location and use it to query as categories.

The problem is that now I'm not able to visit single posts that do not have any referer to taxonomy.

How can I solve? There is a better way to do that?

Comment: Why not just adding an /tax/ or something like this in front of your URLs?